# Crop a PDF file from a predefined line in Python

Tags: python, pdf, crop

I'm trying to clip a specific area of ​​a PDF from a defined line. I want the PDF to be clipped from this line down considering the entire PDF file. The code I'm currently using clips the desired area, but it also considers the area above the specified line, I want it just below the specified line.

My code:

```
# Open PDF file
with open('file.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_file:
    # Create object
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)

    # Create object
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

    # Line
    x1, y1 = (int(66 * 2.83465), int(204 * 2.83465))  # ponto esquerdo da linha
    x2, y2 = (int(143.7 * 2.83465), int(204 * 2.83465))  # ponto direito da linha
    y3 = int(y1 -  100 * 2.83465)  # altura do corte

    # All pages
    for page_num in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
        # Obtenha a página atual
        page = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]

        # Create a new page
        new_page = PyPDF2.PageObject.create_blank_page(
            None, page.mediabox.width, y3 - y1)

        # Define area
        new_page.mediabox.upper_left = (x1, y1 + y3)
        new_page.mediabox.upper_right = (x2, y1)

        # Add new page
        transformation = PyPDF2.Transformation().translate(0, -y1)
        new_page.add_transformation(transformation)
        new_page.merge_page(page)
        pdf_writer.add_page(new_page)

    # Save
    with open('cropped_file.pdf', 'wb') as new_pdf_file:
        pdf_writer.write(new_pdf_file)
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are only interested in the content within rectangle `(x1, y1, x2, y2)`?

Comment: If so, the easiest way is to just set the CropBox to this value. If you need to permanently **_remove_** content outside this area, I would recommend using PyMuPDF redaction annotations.

Comment: In fact, the points x1, y1 and x2, y2 should be the points that define the line. The left point where the line starts and the right point where the line ends. The area I want is all the area below that line.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution using PyMuPDF you could do this:

```py
import fitz  # import PyMuPDF
left = fitz.Point(int(66 * 2.83465), int(204 * 2.83465))
right = fitz.Point(int(143.7 * 2.83465), int(204 * 2.83465))

doc = fitz.open("file.pdf")

# loop over pages of the document and set CropBox to rect
for page in doc:
    # the following rectangle covers everything below the line,
    # and within the left / right borders
    rect = fitz.Rect(left, right.x, page.rect.y1)
    page.set_cropbox(rect)

# finished, save the modified file
doc.save("file-out.pdf")
```

This has changed the visible part of each page to that rectangle.
Please note that any content above that line still exists and could be extracted.

To change that you can in addition "physically" delete stuff above the line. To do this, modify the loop like so:

```py
...
for page in doc:
    # define rectangle for stuff to permanently remove
    to_remove = fitz.Rect(0, 0, page.rect.width, left.y)
    page.add_redact_annot(rect)
    page.apply_redactions()
    # ... like before
    rect = fitz.Rect(left, right.x, page.rect.y1)
    page.set_cropbox(rect)
...
# then save using garbage collection and compression:
doc.save("file-out.pdf", garbage=3, deflate=True)
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks!
But it still wasn't quite right. The first page is correct, but on subsequent pages, it appears the code has also clipped the area above the line. This should only occur on the first page. It's like if I selected the area, clicking and dragging it down, until the end of the last PDF page.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it, using @JorjMcKie solution, thanks!

```
left = fitz.Point(int(66 * 2.83465), int(204 * 2.83465))
right = fitz.Point(int(143.7 * 2.83465), int(204 * 2.83465))
doc = fitz.open("file.pdf")

for i, page in enumerate(doc):
    if i == 0:
        rect = fitz.Rect(left, right.x, page.rect.y1)
    else:
        rect = fitz.Rect(left.x, page.rect.y0, right.x, page.rect.y1)
    
    page.set_cropbox(rect)

doc.save("file_cropped.pdf")
```